# Об употреблении слова "если" с указаниями.

Tags: семантика

Предположим, перед учеником на столике лежат туз, король, дама и валет. Что должен сделать ученик после получения указания "Если на столике есть туз или король, то возьми даму, а если на столике нет ни туза ни короля, то возьми валета."?

Предположим, перед учеником на столике лежат туз, дама и валет. Что должен сделать ученик после получения указания "Если на столике есть туз или король, то возьми даму; а если на столике нет ни туза ни короля, то возьми валета."?

Предположим, перед учеником на столике лежат дама и валет. Что должен сделать ученик после получения указания "Если на столике есть туз или король, то возьми даму; а если на столике нет ни туза ни короля, то возьми валета."?

Answer (score 2):

Ученики не должны играть в такие азартные игры))

Answer (score 1):

А лингвистика здесь причём?

Comment: В данном случае при чем следует писать раздельно. :)

Comment: А в каких случаях слитно?

Comment: Когда присоединительное (добавочное) значение. 

Книга интересная, причем (можно также использовать притом) интересная. 

А я тут при чём?

Comment: Спасибо. Оставлю так в назидание другим безграмотным. ))

Answer (score 0):

В чем, собственно, вопрос заключается?)

Comment: Внесены изменения в формулировку вопроса.